# GitHub Actions + Docker Build: ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/nonexistent'

Tags: docker, github-actions

I have a GitHub Actions workflow where my build is failing because Docker can't install all of libraries from my `requirements.txt` file.

During the `COPY ./requirements.txt .` step and after the packages are finished downloading, the install phase stops with the error: `ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/nonexistent'`

As I was looking through the logs, I noticed:

```
#7 [2/7] RUN adduser --system nonroot
#0 0.105 Adding system user `nonroot' (UID 100) ...
#0 0.105 Adding new user `nonroot' (UID 100) with group `nogroup' ...
#7 0.117 Not creating `/nonexistent'. <---???
#7 DONE 0.7s
```

This is a snippet from a CI workflow that succeeded yesterday:

```
#7 [2/7] RUN adduser --system nonroot
#0 0.099 Adding system user `nonroot' (UID 101) ...
#0 0.099 Adding new user `nonroot' (UID 101) with group `nogroup' ...
#7 0.120 Creating home directory `/home/nonroot' ...
#7 DONE 0.5s
```

I don't understand what is causing this. My Dockerfile has not changed in months.

```
FROM python:3.10-slim

RUN adduser --system nonroot
USER nonroot

WORKDIR /home/nonroot
RUN mkdir /home/nonroot/app

COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD ["python3", "standings.py"]
```

Comment: Hi. I had the same error with the latest python docker images.
My Dockerfile contained 

`RUN addgroup --gid 1001 --system nonroot && adduser --shell /bin/false --disabled-password --uid 1001 --system --group nonroot `

with

`RUN addgroup --gid 1001 nonroot && adduser --shell /bin/false --disabled-password --uid 1001 --gid 1001 nonroot `

it is building now.
There must be a change in the debian adduser api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know what changed but I updated my Dockerfile to:

```
FROM python:3.10-slim

ARG USERNAME=nonroot-user
ARG USER_UID=1000
ARG USER_GID=$USER_UID

RUN groupadd --gid $USER_GID $USERNAME \
    && useradd --uid $USER_UID --gid $USER_GID -m $USERNAME

USER $USERNAME

WORKDIR /home/nonroot
RUN mkdir /home/nonroot/app


COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD ["python3", "stadiums.py"]
```

then all is good. smh.

Answer (score 5):

There has been a change in the behaviour of `adduser` in relation to system users.

**TLDR;**

System users now do not get a home directory by default (actually, they get `/nonexistent`, which should never exist :D). If you still require a home directory for this system user, the `--home DIR` argument must be set.

**Full explanation**

The behavioural change in `adduser` change happened at: https://salsa.debian.org/debian/adduser/-/merge_requests/20, and can also be seen in the manpages of both Debian versions:

- Debian 11 - Bullseye: https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/adduser/adduser.8.en.html#Add_a_system_user
- Debian 12 - Bookworm: https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/adduser/adduser.8.en.html#Add_a_system_user

In this specific case, the Python project has replaced the default `python:3.10` OCI image, from Debian `bullseye` to `bookwork`, at https://github.com/docker-library/python/pull/822, which now uses the new version of `adduser` with the previously linked change.